# LOG4J: One appender by message level

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I want have X number of log4j appenders, one to messages level in files, and all print in console. But I not get.

My actual log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, CONSOLA

log4j.appender.CONSOLA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.WARNLOG=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.file=XX/web/WEB-INF/serverlogs/warn-server.log
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.append=true
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.MaxFileSize=250KB
log4j.appender.WARNLOG.MaxBackupIndex=backup

log4j.appender.FATALLOG=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.threshold=FATAL
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.file=XX/web/WEB-INF/serverlogs/fatal-server.log
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.append=true
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.MaxFileSize=250KB
log4j.appender.FATALLOG.MaxBackupIndex=backup

log4j.logger.com.XX=WARN, WARNLOG
log4j.logger.com.XX=FATAL, FATALLOG
```

**SOLVED:**

I use **LevelRangeFilter**

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FATALLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="xx/web/WEB-INF/serverlogs/fatal-server.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL"/>
            <param name="LevelMin" value="FATAL"/>
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="WARNLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="xx/web/WEB-INF/serverlogs/warn-server.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r %d %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN"/>
            <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN"/>
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.xx">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="FATALLOG" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="WARNLOG" /> 
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Does what you've done send WARN + ERROR + FATAL to WARNLOG, and you only want WARN? Or does it not write to any of those other logs at all? (I know you can get the former behavior by using `log4j.rootLogger=ALL, CONSOLA, WARNLOG, FATALLOG` but I realize that may not be what you need.)

Answer (score 1):

You must have different loggers or use the LevelMatchFilter.

For more information you can search into the complete Log4j manual.

You can found it [here](http://es.scribd.com/doc/7252381/Log4j-The-Complete-Manual)  or [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/ebook/577232/log4j-manual.pdf)

Comment: Hi again and thanks, learning about LevelMatchFilter I see **LevelRangeFilter** better for question, and I see too is better xml than properties file. Thanks for all.

Comment: +1 for the manual link; every time I had looked up Log4J I found links to buy the book when I just wanted one piece of infromation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [LevelMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html) or adapt it.